# how to return incomplete or similar words from mysql query with match function like google

Tags: mysql

How can I make the below query return 'cluburba' or 'club urban' or 'club.urban' too?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Companies 
WHERE MATCH(`Designor Names`) AGAINST ('Cluburban' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION) 
GROUP BY `Designor Names`
```

Comment: How about: `SELECT * 
FROM Companies 
WHERE Designor Names like 'Cluburba%'
GROUP BY Designor Names`

Comment: You may have to go beyond mySQL and use a dedicated search engine for this, like Lucene. https://lucene.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks. It can be the answer for my question

Comment: @Pekka: I may accept your comment as my solution if it is not possible with mysql

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one. I'm assuming the search term is `'cluburban'`...

Fortunately if you match against `'club urban'` it should pick out both `'club urban'` and `'club.urban'` as it will look for both words separately. But your code needs to figure out that the words should be separated by a space first.

You could run your search term through some sort of third-party spell check or dictionary look-up first and hope that it returns `'club urban'` as a possible and run both the original term and any possibles through `MATCH AGAINST` but this wouldn't return `'cluburba'`.

I suspect that MySQL probably won't what you want out of the box and I'd be looking for other plug-ins or packages to do this.

Also `designer` is the correct spelling not `designor`.

Answer (score 1):

Few on my suggestions :

**1. Using multiple like in a query**

*SELECT 
FROM Companies
WHERE Designer Names LIKE '%cluburba%'
AND Designer Names LIKE '%club%'
AND Designer Names LIKE '%urban%' ;*

**2. Using IN query.**

*SELECT * FROM Companies 
            WHERE Designer Names IN ("cluburba", "club","urban");*

**3. Using  Anagram search.**

*SELECT `Designer Names`, 
       0 + IF(`a` > 0, `a` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`b` > 0, `b` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`c` > 0, `c` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`d` > 0, `d` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`e` > 1, `e` - 1, 0) 
       + IF(`f` > 0, `f` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`g` > 0, `g` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`h` > 0, `h` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`i` > 1, `i` - 1, 0) 
       + IF(`j` > 0, `j` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`k` > 0, `k` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`l` > 0, `l` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`m` > 0, `m` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`n` > 1, `n` - 1, 0) 
       + IF(`o` > 0, `o` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`p` > 0, `p` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`q` > 0, `q` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`r` > 0, `r` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`s` > 1, `s` - 1, 0) 
       + IF(`t` > 2, `t` - 2, 0) 
       + IF(`u` > 0, `u` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`v` > 0, `v` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`w` > 0, `w` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`x` > 0, `x` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`y` > 0, `y` - 0, 0) 
       + IF(`z` > 0, `z` - 0, 0) AS difference 
FROM   `Companies` 
WHERE  Length(`Designer Names`) <= 8 
HAVING difference <= 2 ;*

***In all cases use Distinct to avoid the duplicate values.***

Comment: That can be the good solution if I only want to search variations of designer name 'cluburban'. Actually I have 20 thousands of designer names. So will there be any changes in your solution?

Comment: Can you explain Anagram search. what the zeroes are? are they only replacement for my keyword 'cluburban' or have to use it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator "Like"

```
SELECT * FROM Companies where companie like '%Cluburban%'
```

Comment: That won't cover `club urban` nor `club.urban`.

Comment: Ah, the OP changed their question fundamentally. It's not your fault but your answer is now incorrect

Comment: edit my answer if u think this answer is incorrect... your ansewer is correct ?

Comment: I do not have an answer to the question. What the OP wants may not be possible to do with mySQL alone.

Comment: @rdn87. Since your answer cannot be a wrong one for my initial question lines, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thank you @Dhay 
my bad mood is because they think they are teachers and then do not even know the risposta..ma give negative ratings to others ...